Nodemon consistently shuts down my machine
Running on Windows 11 Pro v10.0.22635, VS Code 1.91.0, node v22.3.0, nodemon v3.1.4.
My machine has 128GB RAM, AMD 3960X CPU.
In VS Code, tried multiple separate very simple projects (one server.js file). When running nodemon, it appears to run the code in the server.js file, then immediately shuts down the computer.
This happens every time, regardless of the project or any other installed packages.
I've tried to create the most stripped-down project possible, with just a console log in the server.js file, and nodemon as the only dependency. It still shuts down the computer every time.
I've tried running with a globally installed nodemon as well as one installed locally to the project.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and nodemon.
